# Error "The resource cannot be found" when play video

Tags: asp.net

> I had my **asp.net** website to play video , i did my code but i have
>   error "**The resource cannot be found**"

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DL_Media" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <iframe width="215" height="160" src='<%#Eval("Media_File")%>' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen
                                runat="server"></iframe>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
```

> Media_File is video path as "~/res/Files/sp.flv" on DB and the physical file "video" in file
>   directory at the project root .

Comment: check our database connectivity path and file location path.

Answer (score 0):

Remove '~'sign path and put relative path 'res/Files/sp.flv' if 'res' directory is at the top level d

Update :

Just use the `HTML5`

`<video src="<%= pathToVideoFile %>" />`

element. Browsers will render it fine by themselves

Update :

```
<video width="356" height="200" controls poster="full/http/link/to/image/file.png"  >

<source src="full/link/to/http/mp4/video/file.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

<source src="full/link/to/http/ogv/video/file.ogv" type="video/ogg" />

<source src="full/link/to/http/webm/video/file.wbem" type="video/webm" />

<em>Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</em>

</video>
```

Comment: window appeared to save the video , i want to display it

Comment: i edited the code but the video didn't play only blank page although it retrieve the video path from db